# jammed eclipse after installing some blackberry plugin

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have made the blunder not to back up eclipse before installing some old Blackberry plugin over it. Now it would not start, showing an error message box: "An error has occurred. See the logfile C:\eclipse...."

Logfile first few lines read:

```
!SESSION 2011-02-15 19:46:31.828 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2011-02-15 19:46:32.703
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.101.R35x_v20090807-1100
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1313)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-02-15 19:46:32.703
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.100.v20090520-1905.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-02-15 19:46:32.703
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

There is also another logfile - made at blackberry plugin installation reporting

Installation: Successful.

```
1073 Successes
0 Warnings
0 NonFatalErrors
0 FatalErrors
```

and containing 1073 files it has added to the preexistent installation. It does not say anything to any cfg file modifications or such. Any way I can, maybe, revert the plugin installation based on that logfile ? Any other tip ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exactly know which plugins/features is causing the problem, you can try to manually delete files related to them in %ECLIPSE_INSTALL%\plugins and %ECLIPSE_INSTALL%\features. You should backup your files before deleting!

Personally, I would reinstall Eclipse from scratch, debugging that can be time consuming!

Comment: Snap.. just found out the damn 'plugin' was not actually a plugin but a full blown eclipse installation. There went my eclipse .. PHP, Java, SVN, etc. Gonna waste days on it to bring back. Hmm.. I do have some paragon backups now :)

Comment: I've experienced similar problems with Eclipse in the past. On top of that, we were developing our own plugin to handle our XML files with a kind of Visual Graph. I've blown a tons of installations :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the folder from the plugins directory and restart eclipse.